# Codename One Windows Push

Tags: codenameone

We are running one of our apps on Windows - Currently a Windows Desktop Build, which we then package using MSIX and distribute via the Windows Store.

We would like to add Push Notifications to the app.

1.) I've implemented the push registration on the app which works well for on Android and iOS - but on the Desktop build the Registration callbacks do not fire.

Is push notification on the client side available for the Desktop Builds?

2.) Using the UWP build, the Push Registration works and we get a Push Key for the app.
When we try to send a message to the app via the https://push.codenameone.com/ url (using a POST request from our Java Back-end or a manual GET in the web browser) we get the following error,

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: URI is not absolute
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    ar.com.fernandospr.wns.client.WnsClient.push(WnsClient.java:135)
    ar.com.fernandospr.wns.client.WnsClient.push(WnsClient.java:172)
    ar.com.fernandospr.wns.WnsService.pushToast(WnsService.java:153)
    ar.com.fernandospr.wns.WnsService.pushToast(WnsService.java:141)
    com.codename1.server.push.SendPush.service(SendPush.java:708)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

The problem seems to be with the '**cn1-win-**' part in the device ID,
cn1-win-aHR0cHM6Ly93bn.....

Removing that results in the server responding correct with invalid device id.
Removing any other character in the id does not seem to make a difference and you still get the Internal Server Error.

Here is our sending code on our back end.

The 'param' Object being used is a Entity Class which stores the Push setting.

param.getServiceURL() = https://push.codenameone.com/push/push

We are still testing so I hard coded the Windows SID and Claim Secret - Actual code does not contain the ....

```
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(param.getServiceURL()).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

        String queryString = "token=" + param.getAndroidToken();
        
        queryString = queryString + "&type=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getPushType()), "UTF-8");
        queryString = queryString + "&body=" + URLEncoder.encode(theMessage, "UTF-8");
        
        if (param.isTestPush()) {
            //Limit device to Testing Device
            String x = "&device=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getTestPushKey().trim(), "UTF-8");
            queryString = queryString.concat(x);
        } else {
            //Add Devices to send to
            for (String deviceId : devices) {
                String x = "&device=" + URLEncoder.encode(deviceId, "UTF-8");
                queryString = queryString.concat(x);
            }
        }
        
        //Android
        queryString = queryString + "&auth=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getAuthorizationKey(), "UTF-8");

        //iOS
        queryString = queryString + "&certPassword=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getIosCertPassword(), "UTF-8");
        queryString = queryString + "&cert=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getIosCertUrl(), "UTF-8");

        //Windows
        queryString = queryString + "&sid=" + URLEncoder.encode("ms-app://s-1-15-2-.....", "UTF-8");
        queryString = queryString + "&client_secret=" + URLEncoder.encode("VUbR8T1O......", "UTF-8");

        try ( OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
            output.write(queryString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
        int c = connection.getResponseCode();
        
        if (c == 200) {
            //Success - Read JSON to check indavidual device sent status
        } else {
            //Error - Sending Failed - Read connection.getErrorStream and print to logs
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet code is missing some critical parts

First this

```
try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
      output.write(queryString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

should be

```
try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
     output.write(queryString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Second: the following code to read response from the server is missing,

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String input;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("input = " + input);
    sb.append(input.trim());
}
reader.close();

resp = sb.toString();
System.out.println("RESP<< " + resp);
```

Assuming you have valid; FCM Key, Codename One token & android device id, I've modified your code to the following complete code snippet which sends push notification successfully to android device. With necessary iOS & Windows credentials, it should also send to iOS & Windows phone.

```
private String fcmKey = "";
private String cn1Token = "";
private String pushUrl = "https://push.codenameone.com/push/push";
private String deviceId = "";
private String deviceId2 = "";
private String msg = "test push note";
String resp;


public String sendPushNote() {

    try {
        //HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(param.getServiceURL()).openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(pushUrl).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

        //String queryString = "token=" + param.getAndroidToken();
        String queryString = "token=" + cn1Token;

        //queryString = queryString + "&type=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getPushType()), "UTF-8");
        queryString = queryString + "&type=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf("1"), "UTF-8");
        
        //queryString = queryString + "&body=" + URLEncoder.encode(theMessage, "UTF-8");
        queryString = queryString + "&body=" + URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8");

        /*if (param.isTestPush()) {
        //Limit device to Testing Device
        String x = "&device=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getTestPushKey().trim(), "UTF-8");
        queryString = queryString.concat(x);
        } else {
        //Add Devices to send to
        for (String deviceId : devices) {
            String x = "&device=" + URLEncoder.encode(deviceId, "UTF-8");
            queryString = queryString.concat(x);
        }
        }*/
        
        String x = "&device=" + URLEncoder.encode(deviceId2.trim(), "UTF-8");
        queryString = queryString.concat(x);

        //Android
        //queryString = queryString + "&auth=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getAuthorizationKey(), "UTF-8");
        queryString = queryString + "&auth=" + URLEncoder.encode(fcmKey, "UTF-8");

        //iOS
        /*queryString = queryString + "&certPassword=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getIosCertPassword(), "UTF-8");
          queryString = queryString + "&cert=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getIosCertUrl(), "UTF-8");

          //Windows
          queryString = queryString + "&sid=" + URLEncoder.encode("ms-app://s-1-15-2-.....", "UTF-8");
          queryString = queryString + "&client_secret=" + URLEncoder.encode("VUbR8T1O......", "UTF-8");*/

        
        /*try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
           output.write(queryString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }*/
        
        
        try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
           output.write(queryString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        resp = "FAIL0 " + e;
        }

        int c = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (c == 200) {
        //Success - Read JSON to check indavidual device sent status

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String input;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("input = " + input);
            sb.append(input.trim());
        }
        reader.close();

        resp = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("RESP<< " + resp);

        } else {
        //Error - Sending Failed - Read connection.getErrorStream and print to logs
        resp = "FAIL1 RespCode " + c;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        resp = "FAIL2" + ex.getMessage();
    }

    return resp;
}
```

P.S. since you have already set

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
```

you can simplify queryString to

```
String queryString = "token=" + cn1Token
                + "&device=" + deviceId2
                + "&type=" + "1"
                + "&auth=" + fcmKey
                + "&body=" + msg;
```

Comment: Nice. Notice that the last bit is probably not right since OP wants to push to a Windows device.

Comment: You mean simplifying "String queryString"? If so it works when sending to Android device. Any reason why it might not work when sending to Windows phone?

Comment: You need an additional parameter for Windows the `sid`.

Comment: Yes, for windows phone.   + "&sid=" + sidValue + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret; should be appended to the  "String queryString". And for iOS +  "&certPassword=" + certPwd + "&cert=" + cert; should also be appended to the  "String queryString".

Answer (score 0):

Only the UWP port will work with Push. The desktop build is a standard Java SE application and doesn't include push capabilities.

You need to send a push via the Codename One push servers. See this: https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_sending_push_message_from_a_java_or_generic_server

Comment: We are sending via the Codename One Push Server like the example in the dev guide shows. We are only passing in the Token, 1 Device, Type, Body, SID and Client Secret. It is the Codename One push server that is then responding with the 'URI is not absolute' internal server error.

Comment: What's the JSON response that you're getting? That isn't an error we generate so it's either an error we got or a client side error. The JSON response will help in understanding which.

Comment: We are not getting any JSON Back, the request fails with a 500 Status Code and the Error Stream returns the javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: URI is not absolute stack trace in the original question.

Comment: 500 means a server error which means the request was invalid. Can you show the content of the post request as it was generated to our server?
Unless this request is working for other platforms in which case this would be interesting.

Comment: Updated question with Sending code

Comment: Can you print the query string and send it to us in the website chat so we can reproduce the issue? I don't see this in our logs so I'm guessing it failed beforehand.